# How to align view elements in interface builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I try to align my view elements. This is very hard because there aligned according to the other elements.

[image]

So when I pull the cursor down the whole thing jumps to the next blue dotted line. Is it possible to align them stepless?

Comment: thanks that solves my problem. make that an answer ;)

Comment: Suggest this question belongs on another site, such as superuser, because it is about using an application rather than programming. Its not a huge deal, but I think you'll find that community is better suited for this kind of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To bypass Interface Builder's "snapping" to other controls, you can select the control you wish to move and use the arrow keys to fine-tune the location.

Comment: Sometimes you would still like to use the mouse because the behavior of the elements between the buttons and clicking and dragging can differ (like with automatic adjustment of subviews with one and not the other).

There should be a snap override key like every other program in the world has.